# Backflow Preventer / Vacuum Breaker that doesn't spray water everywhere?

Tags: plumbing, irrigation

I water my garden on a timer with an small irrigation system.  Last year towards the end of the season, any time the water pressure changed inside the house, everything by the spigot was soaked with water because of the drop in pressure.  It seemed to get worse as the season went on, and this year, is completely ridiculous.

Is my backflow preventer simply worn out?  Are there any devices that would allow the pressure in the line to remain intact regardless of the drop in pressure in the house?  I'd rather not spray my hardiplanks with water Every Single Time someone turns on a faucet or flushes the toilet.

What options are available to me?

Comment: Is this a screw on Backflow preventer?  You mention spigot... a pic would help.

Comment: Yes, it is.  It is semi-permanent in that the screw has been broken off, but I have seen quite a few videos on how to remove it.
 Looks a lot like this: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S-eiVa1eL._AC_UL115_.jpg

Comment: Yep that was my guess... just drill the screw out and replace it.